# Is there an easier way to answer this dice rolling probability question?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

**Two fair dice are rolled. What is the probability that the sum of the numbers on the dice is 9?**

The way I solved this was:
All possible outcomes = 6 * 6 = 36
Then listed all the outcomes and came up with 4. 
*So my answer is 4/36*

I am wondering if there is a way to solve this without having to list all the possible outcomes. Is there a way to find them mathematically?

Comment: Formula (10) on [MathWorld: Dice](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html) shows how you can calculate this probability directly, but you can see that it's a lot easier to just count the possible sums when you have very few dice and sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to list *all* the outcomes, only the ones that fit your "criteria"

So if $n_1$ = value on first die

$n_2$ = value on second die

9 = $n_1 + n_2$
Start with $n_1$ being the highest value it can be, $n_1 = 6 \rightarrow n_2 = 3$

Then decrease $n_1$, increase $n_2 \rightarrow n_1=5, n_2 =4$

You continue this procedure twice more until $n_2$ = 6 (and $n_1 =3$), since you can't go any further.

So there are 4 combinations.